# JavaScript userscript does not run itself

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm using Greasemonkey and I was trying to write my own userscript.
I've already got the code, but it's not "running", dunno why.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Image link
// @version    0.1
// @include      http://*.*
// @run-at      document-end
// ==/UserScript==
var img = document.getElementById('image'),
style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
link = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);
alert(link);
```

What can I do to make it actually work?

Comment: what are you trying to do with your script?

Comment: I'm trying to get an image link from `<a id="image" style="background-image: url(http://images.example.com/12345.jpg); opacity: 1;"></a>` in a Pop-up alert.

Comment: While the script is not robust, it nevertheless *does* work on *static* pages that have an `#image` node with the proper style.  **How** does it not work for you?  On **what page, exactly**?  What's your browser version?  GM version?  **What does the error console say?**

Comment: It had something to do with the page's script, which was blocking mine from running. Thanks, but I already threw that out ;)

Comment: Hey, can you answer your own question (if you're still around) so this quits showing up as unanswered so I don't keep reading it every day lol

Answer (score 0):

Code is good, but the website was broken. It works on a different one.